# Java "The blank final field may not have been initialized" Anonymous Interface vs Lambda Expression

Tags: java, constructor, lambda, compiler-construction, java-8

I've recently been encountering the error message "The blank final field obj may not have been initialized".

Usually this is the case if you try to refer to a field that is possibly not assigned to a value yet. Example class:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Object obj;
    public Foo() {
        obj.toString(); // error           (1)
        obj = new Object();
        obj.toString(); // just fine       (2)
    }
}
```

I use Eclipse. In the line `(1)` I get the error, in the line `(2)` everything works. **So far that makes sense.**

Next I try to access `obj` within an anonymous interface I create inside the constructor.

```
public class Foo {
    private Object obj;
    public Foo() {
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                obj.toString(); // works fine
            }
        };
        obj = new Object();
        obj.toString(); // works too
    }
}
```

This works, too, since I do not access `obj` in the moment I create the interface. I could also pass my instance to somewhere else, then initialize the object `obj` and then run my interface. (However it would be appropriate to check for `null` before using it). **Still makes sense.**

**But now I shorten the creation of my `Runnable` instance to** the burger-arrow version by using **a lambda expression**:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Object obj;
    public Foo() {
        Runnable run = () -> {
            obj.toString(); // error
        };
        obj = new Object();
        obj.toString(); // works again
    }
}
```

And here is where I can't follow anymore. Here I get the warning again. I am aware that the compiler doesn't handle lambda expressions as usual initializations, it doesn't "replace it by the long version". However, why does this affect the fact that I do not run the code part in my `run()` method at creation time of the `Runnable` object? I am still able to do the initialization *before* I invoke `run()`. So technically it is possible not to encounter a `NullPointerException` here. (Though it would be better to check for `null` here, too. But this convention is another topic.)

What is the mistake I make? What is handled so differently about lambda that it influences my object usage the way it does?

I thank you for any further explanations.

Comment: What warning/error do you get with the final version? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get the exact error as mentioned in the title. And I use Java 8. I think otherwise I wouldn't even be able to use lambda, right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the compiler version. It's java 8, but which release version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error for your final case with Eclipse's compiler.

However, the reasoning for the Oracle compiler I can imagine is the following: inside a lambda, the value of `obj` must be captured at declaration time. That is, it must be initialized when it is declared inside the lambda body.

But, in this case, Java should capture the value of the `Foo` instance rather than `obj`. It can then access `obj` through the (initialized) `Foo` object reference and invoke its method. This is how the Eclipse compiler compiles your piece of code.

This is hinted at in the specification, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3):

> The timing of method reference expression evaluation is more complex
>   than that of lambda expressions (§15.27.4). When a method reference
>   expression has an expression (rather than a type) preceding the ::
>   separator, that subexpression is evaluated immediately. **The result of
>   evaluation is stored until the method of the corresponding functional
>   interface type is invoked**; at that point, the result is used as the
>   target reference for the invocation. This means the expression
>   preceding the :: separator is evaluated only when the program
>   encounters the method reference expression, and is not re-evaluated on
>   subsequent invocations on the functional interface type.

A similar thing happens for

```
Object obj = new Object(); // imagine some local variable
Runnable run = () -> {
    obj.toString(); 
};
```

Imagine `obj` is a local variable, when the lambda expression code is executed, `obj` is evaluated and produces a reference. This reference is stored in a field in the `Runnable` instance created. When `run.run()` is called, the instance uses the reference value stored.

This cannot happen if `obj` isn't initialized. For example

```
Object obj; // imagine some local variable
Runnable run = () -> {
    obj.toString(); // error
};
```

The lambda cannot capture the value of `obj`, because it doesn't have a value yet. It's effectively equivalent to

```
final Object anonymous = obj; // won't work if obj isn't initialized
Runnable run = new AnonymousRunnable(anonymous);
...
class AnonymousRunnable implements Runnable {
    public AnonymousRunnable(Object val) {
        this.someHiddenRef = val;
    }
    private final Object someHiddenRef;
    public void run() {
        someHiddenRef.toString(); 
    }
}
```

This is how the Oracle compiler is currently behaving for your snippet.

However, the Eclipse compiler is, instead, not capturing the value of `obj`, it's capturing the value of `this` (the `Foo` instance). It's effectively equivalent to

```
final Foo anonymous = Foo.this; // you're in the Foo constructor so this is valid reference to a Foo instance
Runnable run = new AnonymousRunnable(anonymous);
...
class AnonymousRunnable implements Runnable {
    public AnonymousRunnable(Foo foo) {
        this.someHiddenRef = foo;
    }
    private final Foo someHiddenFoo;
    public void run() {
        someHiddenFoo.obj.toString(); 
    }
}
```

Which is fine because you assume that the `Foo` instance is completely initialized by the time `run` is invoked.

Comment: Mysterious. Which version of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: @SteffenT Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600

Comment: I think it doesn't work with that version, I updated to 4.4.2 a couple of weeks ago and reinstalled it today again. That's something else making me wonder, because this update of Eclipse suddenly created a list of errors in my workspace.

Comment: That edit is interesting. Thank you! However, that doesn't mean I like lambda better now. This is way too confusing if you're not that much into how the compiler works.

Comment: @SteffenT I tried to find a JLS section that explains the capture logic but I couldn't find it. I try to look at it like this: the body of the lambda expression is parsed and all variables that aren't declared in the body are extracted. Then the current values of the variables is evaluated and bound to them. They do not change for the lifecycle of the resulting  instance.

Comment: If they do not change, how can I then access any fields from within?

Comment: @SteffenT I don't understand. The variable will have stored some constant value. If that value is of a reference type, you can dereference it to invoke a method or access a field.

Comment: This would mean I could not access a field outside. If it stores its own constant value at the time of creation, I could not be able to access the changing value of an outside field. Or do I miss sth here?

Comment: @SteffenT See my last code snippet. That is equivalent to what I think a compiler should do for _your_ last snippet. The lambda will store the value of `Foo.this` in a `private` and `final` field. That is, it is immutable/constant. You can still access its field `obj` though. Or invoke any of its methods.

Comment: only `this` is captured, never instance variables of `this`. That's the behavior of Oracle javac too, as spec dictates. The issue originates from somewhere else. Unfortunately, eclipse is wrong here, per spec.

Comment: @bayou.io I would expect `this` to be captured. Eclipse compiles it correctly for me and I can see in debug mode that it has captured the `Foo` instance. It fails with the compiler that comes with Oracle's java `build 1.8.0_20-b26`

Comment: unfortunately for eclipe, it's a bug, not a feature:)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ahhh okay, that explains a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: I don’t get how the specification of what happens with the expression before the `::` of a method reference should explain anything about a lambda expression usage where no method references are involved.

Comment: @Holger I wanted to show something in the specification that explained how the values of variables are captured. I couldn't find anything relating to variables in lambda bodies. This was the next best thing.

Comment: But this is an entirely different thing, the expression before the `::` doesn’t need to be a variable at all and it’s evaluated immediately. In contrast, references to instance fields are evaluated when the lambda’s body is executed.

Comment: @Holger Maybe my wording is misleading. I'm not trying to say it's the same thing. I'm trying to highlight how values are captured. This method reference explanation for expression preceding the `::` was the closest thing I could find.

Comment: Just ran into this. I think this needs a JEP. Maybe an annotation on the lambda like @Async to make the compiler ignore uninitialized instance variables. Until then, would be nice to have an Eclipse compiler fix.

Answer (score 17):

You can bypass the problem by

```
        Runnable run = () -> {
            (this).obj.toString(); 
        };
```

This was discussed during lambda development, basically the lambda body is treated as local code during *definite assignment analysis*.

Quoting Dan Smith, spec tzar, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024809

> The rules carve out two exceptions: ... ii) a use from inside of an anonymous class is okay. There is no exception for a use inside of a lambda expression

Frankly I and some other people thought the decision is wrong. The lambda only captures `this`, not `obj`. This case should have been treated the same as anonymous class. The current behavior is problematic for many legit use cases . Well, you can always bypass it using the trick above- fortunately 
*definite assignment analysis* is not too smart and we can fool it.

Comment: I don’t think that the technical aspects of the compilation should drive the formal definitions of the specification. Technically, lambdas, as compiled today, capture `this` to access fields, even `final` fields, but that might change in future versions. And the flow analysis does not prevent the `Runnable`’s `run` method to be invoked before `obj` has been initialized. And lambdas should *not* behave like inner classes as they are not inner classes. They don’t behave like them in many aspects and making them behave like them in this aspect would be a step backwards.

Comment: capturing-`this`-only is in the spec, and I don't think they can change that in future versions.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the relevant part of the spec? I didn’t find anything about such a behavior in the specification.

Comment: @Holger - dude, I should - but I really don't want to dive in the spec again; it's a beast.

Comment: @Holger - anyway, it is a critical distinction - whether `obj` is evaluated at the time lamda is executed, or at the time lambda is created. this must be settled by the spec, and it's unlikely to change in future.

Comment: Keep in mind that we are talking about a `final` variable here which shouldn’t change after its assignment. That’s why insisting on the variable being assigned before the lambda expression is such important: it ensures that it doesn’t make a difference when the value will be read. The only thing I found in the spec is that names within the lambda expression have the same meaning as for its surrounding context and that aligns to the observed behavior.

Comment: in the surround context, `obj` means `this.obj`. that's also the case in the lambda body - `obj` means - load `this`, then access its `obj` field. that is semantically different from accessing some other synthetic field capturing `obj` itself.

Comment: compiler cannot enforce that a final instance field be initialized before access. and the spec does not try to do that. there are too many ways to circumvent it.

Comment: ahem and what is this question all about? It’s about the fact, that for an expression consisting of a simple name or a simple name qualified with `this` (without braces), the compiler *does* enforce this rule. Hence for these kinds of access, the field doesn’t need to be accessed via repeated reads. The rest is given by the [Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5): “… *compilers are allowed to keep the value of a final field cached in a register and not reload it from memory in situations where a non-final field would have to be reloaded*”

Comment: for JMM, it's important to know when a read action occurs. for a final field, it's important to know when the 1st read occurs in a thread (subsequent reads can be optimized). in that regard, there's a difference between capturing `this` or `obj`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78553/discussion-between-bayou-io-and-holger).

Comment: Sadly, the `(this).` workaround no longer works in Java 9, for either OpenJDK/Oracle or Oracle.  Alternative hoops must now be jumped through in order to get reasonable (and functioning!) lambda-using code to refer to `final`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a utility method to force capturing `this` only. This works with Java 9 too.

```
public static <T> T r(T object) {
    return object;
}
```

Now, you can rewrite your lambda like this:

```
Runnable run = () -> r(this).obj.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class ObjectHolder {
    private final Object obj;
    public Supplier<Object> sup = () -> obj; // error

    public ObjectHolder(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

And resolved it this way:

```
public Supplier<Object> sup = () -> ((ObjectHolder)this).obj;
```

Neither `this.obj` nor `ObjectHolder.this.obj` worked in Eclipse (though the latter worked for the standard JDK compiler).

In your case, use this workaround, it is safe for all compilers:

```
((Foo)this).obj.toString();
```

Another solution is to use a getter. In my example, it looks like this:

```
public Supplier<Object> sup = () -> getObj();

private Object getObj() {
    return obj;
}
```