# Variable referencing from a lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, anonymous-function, final

Why does Java allow this,

```java
class Test {
    boolean a;
    public void test() {
        ...
        object.method(e -> a = true);
    }
}
```

But not this,

```java
class Test {
    public void test() {
        boolean a;
        ...
        object.method(e -> a = true);
    }
}
```

For the second example, it throws:
`local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`

The only difference in second example is that the variable is declared inside the method instead of the class itself. I am a beginner in Java programming, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The local variable is on the stack, so there's no way of guaranteeing it will stay around for the lifetime of the lambda.

Comment: First example won't compile since static method don't have access to non-static class field.

Comment: @MedvedievV. My bad, I have made the necessary edits. Now does it look correct?

Comment: @tgdavies But the lambda will live as long as the test method lives, right? Can you give an example where the lambda function could be executed even though we have exited from the test method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example works, because `a = true` is actually shorthand for `this.a = true`, and `this` is always `final` (so says the Java Specification).

Comment: If `this` is final, then how can I change instance variables using, for example, `this.x = y`

Comment: @malibu `this.x = y` is changing the value of field `x`, it is not changing the value of the `this` reference variable.

Comment: That makes sense. Also, can you explain why we have the restriction of making variable final for second example?  @tgdavies explained "there's no way of guaranteeing it will stay around for the lifetime of the lambda", but I didn't get when would that be possible.

Comment: @malibu See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075832/5221149).