# Java 8 forEach returning property from inside loop

Tags: java, collections, lambda

I need to return a property of a certain object from which I need to access within a `forEach` loop. Basically I have a `user` object that that has a property of `List<UserLocation>` and inside the `UserLocation` object is a `Location` object with a property of `location_id`. If the `store_id` on the `user` object matches the `store_id` on the `UserLocation` object, that is the one I need to get the `location_id` from. However, the issue I am getting is that it says the variable used inside the lambda expression should be final or effectively final. See code below.

```
User user = getUser(request);
Integer locationId;

user.getUserLocations().forEach(ul -> {
    if (ul.getStoreId() == user.getStoreId()) {
        locationId= ul.getUserLocations().getLocationId();
    }
});
```

Any advice or solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: Java doesn't have closures unfortunately, that's why you get compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is: you cannot assign from inside a closure. You could work around this by making a mutable container, an array or a list, but a better approach is to use stream's [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method:

```
Optional<Integer> optLocationId = user.getUserLocations().stream()
    .filter(ul -> ul.getStoreId() == user.getStoreId())
    .findFirst();
if (optLocationId.isPresent()) {
    Integer locationId = optLocationId.get().getUserLocations().getLocationId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done better without `forEach`, assuming you only need to find one location :

```
Integer locationId = user.getUserLocations()
                         .stream()
                         .filter(ul -> ul.getStoreId() == user.getStoreId())
                         .findAny()
                         .map(ul -> ul.getLocation().getLocationId())
                         .orElse (0); // default value in case no match is found
```

P.S. I'm assuming `ul.getUserLocations()` is a typo, and should be `ul.getLocation()`, since you wrote that `inside the UserLocation object is a Location object` and `getUserLocations()` seems to be a method of the `User` class, not the `UserLocation` class.