# additional arguments to Java Lambda expressions - how?

Tags: java, lambda

How can I use additional variables inside of named Java Lambda Expressions, as I can do in an anonymous one? I found a workaround (method returns a Lambda), but out of curiosity: can this be formulated in pure Lambda syntax as well? I can't find an answer in the usual tutorials and references.

Please consider the following example code:

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().filter( i -> i<3 ).toArray();
```

I can give a name to this anonymous Lambda:

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().filter(LessThanThree).toArray();
[...]
Predicate<Integer> LessThanThree = i -> i<3;
```

But if I want to use a variable instead of the constant, the same syntax will not work. because I can't find a way to declare parameters to the named Lambda:

Edit: Thank you, dpr, for hinting that this is a matter of scope! I enhanced to following block of code to try to clarify what I'm interested in.

```
filterIt(3);
[...]
void filterIt(int x) {
    Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().filter(LessThanX).toArray();
}
[...]
Predicate<Integer> LessThanX = i -> i<x; // won't compile!
```

The workaround seems to be a method that returns the Lambda:

```
private Predicate<Integer> lessThanX(int x) {
    return i -> i<x;
}
```

But: is there a way to formulate this in pure named Lambda?

Comment: Of course final variables are possible. A mix of functional, side-effect free programming and using variables is not advisable.

Comment: Actually your code compiles. At least if you declare the lambda and x in the same scope.

Comment: It works when `x` is either a local variable that is (effectively) final, or when x is a field. The latter is probably what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you could use a `java.util.function.BiPredicate` instead of the normal predicate

```
BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> lessThan = (i, j) -> i < j;
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().filter(i -> lessThan.test(i, 3)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you require tests with more than 2 inputs you might need to write your own `@FunctionalInterface` that you can use as lambda.

Comment: I didn't notice there was a `BiPredicate` until now (which is why I used a `BiFunction` in my answer). +1

Comment: @Eran I was actually surprised that there is no `TriPredicate` ;) Apart from the fixed return type of the `BiPredicate` my answer is of course essentially the same as your's.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a second variable (such as x in your example), you no longer have a `Predicate<Integer>`. You have a `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Boolean>` (i.e. a function with two parameters that returns a `Boolean`).

You can define a lambda expression and assign it to a `BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Boolean>`:

```
BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Boolean> LessThanX = (i,x) -> i<x;
```

In order to convert it to a `Predicate<Integer>`, you'll need a second lambda expression that relies on the first one:

```
Predicate<Integer> LessThan3 = i -> LessThanX.apply (i, 3);
```

Of course you can use the `BiFunction` directly:

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().filter(i -> LessThanX.apply (i, 3)).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that this lambda: `a -> a < b` takes only one parameter - `a`. The value of `x` is baked into the function.

When you use this in a loop:

```
for(int b = 0; b<20; b++) {
   IntStream.range(15,25)
        .filter( a -> a < b)
        ...;
}
```

You're creating a new predicate each time around the `b` loop:

```
  a -> a < 0
  a -> a < 1
  a -> a < 2
```

... and so on. In this example if `b` were not *effectively final* the compiler would forbid it.

You can do exactly the same thing by defining a local `Predicate`:

```
for(int b = 0; b<20; b++) {
   Predicate<Integer> lessThanB = a -> a < b;
   IntStream.range(15,25)
        .filter(lessThanB)
        ...;
}
```

But you can't define that lessThanB outside the scope in which `b` is a final variable.

You can define a `BiPredicate`:

```
BiPredicate<Integer,Integer> lessThan = (a,b) -> a < b;
```

... but you can't use `BiPredicate` everywhere you can use `Predicate` - e.g. in `Stream.filter()`. *Currying* turns a `BiPredicate` into a `Predicate` with one of the parameters baked in:

```
final int x = 5;
Predicate<Integer> lessThanX = n -> lessThan.test(n,x);
```

... and you can do this inline in a `filter()`:

```
.filter( n -> lessThan.test(n,x))
```

However you've not gained much -- you're still creating a new `Predicate` for each new value of `x`.

---

There is no `TriPredicate` but a principle of FP is that a chain of *n* single-param functions is equivalent to one *n*-param function. You don't *need* more than one parameter (`BiPredicate` is a courtesy)

That is, instead of:

```
TriFunction<String, String, String, User> finder = (company, dept, name) -> { ...}`
```

... you'd have:

```
Function<String, Function<String, Function<String, User>>> format =
      company -> dept -> name -> 
          String.format("Company: %s\nDept: %s\nName: %s", company, dept, name);
```

To be called as `String s = format.apply("Daimler").apply("Accounts").apply("John Doe")`

...or less generally, a three-param `Predicate` would be:

```
Function<String, Function<String, Predicate<String>>> userExists = 
    company -> dept -> name ->  somethingThatReturnsBoolean(company, dept, name);
```

... called as:

```
boolean exists = 
    userExists.apply("Daimler").apply("Accounts").test("John Doe")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles!

```
int x = 3;
Predicate<Integer> LessThanThree = i -> i<x;
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().filter(LessThanThree).toArray();
```

keep in mind that x has to be [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)!
as soon as you add another line like `x = 4` it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet already works perfect and it should.

```
        List<Integer> vals = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        int compare_int = 2;
        //Add this compare_int = 4;//Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final
        Predicate<Integer> GT_3 = integer -> integer > compare_int;
        System.out.println(vals.stream().filter(GT_3).count());//prints 3
```

I prefer it to be a **method** than being a variable coz, the method gives more of a meaning to the operation or the comparison. Ofcourse for this small case of checking greater than doesn't have impact, but a real case scenario, methods are better and it also allows you to share across within the `class`'s methods.