# Java: Proper way of creating a list containing all not-in-intersect elements from two given lists based on a specific attribute?

Tags: java

Given two Lists of Objects, I'd be able to tell which items are not in their intersect based on one of their attributes. Let's look at the following example:

I have a class `Foo` that has two attributes: `boo` and `placeholder`

```
class Foo {
    private int boo;
    private int placeholder = 1;

    public Foo(int boo) {
        this.boo = boo;
    }

    public int getBoo() {
        return boo;
    }
}
```

Now I am creating two Lists from that (let's say this is my input)

```
    List<Foo> list1 = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    list1.add(new Foo(1));
    list1.add(new Foo(2));
    list1.add(new Foo(3));

    List<Foo> list2 = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    list2.add(new Foo(0));
    list2.add(new Foo(1));
    list2.add(new Foo(2));
```

And now I'd like to say which Items are in `list1` and not in `list2` or in `list2` and not in `list1` based on their attribute `boo`. So in the above example I want a `List<Foo> notInIntersectList` that contains one `Foo(0)` and one `Foo(3)`.

```
    List<Foo> notInIntersectList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    list1.forEach(li1foo -> {
        boolean inBothLists = false;
        list2.forEach(li2foo -> {
            if (li1foo.getBoo() == li2foo.getBoo()) {
                inBothLists = true;
            }
        });
        if (!inBothLists) {
            notInIntersectList.add(li1foo);
        }
    });
    //now I covered all items in list1 but not in list2. Now do this again with lists swapped, so I can also cover those.
    //...
```

Sadly I am getting `Local variable inBothLists defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final` as an error. How is this issue solved properly, since this seems not to be the "right" solution?

Comment: Try with a traditional for loop, instead of overusing a lambda, and you should be fine. **Code isn't better just because it has a lambda expression!** `list2.forEach(li2foo -> {` is not more elegant than `for(Foo li2foo : list2) {`, and you lose the ability to `break` and modify local variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot mutate variables inside a lambda expression (See: [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final))

Here's a way to fix your code (fun with Streams)

```
List<Foo> notInIntersectList = list1.stream()
        .filter(fooElementFromList1 -> list2
                .stream()
                .noneMatch(fooElementFromList2 -> fooElementFromList2.getBoo() == fooElementFromList1.getBoo()))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

list2.stream()
        .filter(fooElementFromList2 -> list1
            .stream()
            .noneMatch(fooElementFromList1 -> fooElementFromList1.getBoo() == fooElementFromList2.getBoo()))
        .forEach(notInIntersectList::add);
```

The complexity of this is `O(n*m)` (where `n` and `m` are the number of elements in list1 and list2 respectively).

To do this in `O(n+m)`, you can use a Set. For this, you need a `equals` and `hashcode` method on the `Foo` class. This considers two `Foo` instances as equal only based on the value of the instance variable `boo`.

```
class Foo {
    ....

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Foo other = (Foo) obj;
        return boo == other.boo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return boo;
    }
}
```

And use a `Set` for this as

```
Set<Foo> fooSet1 = new HashSet<>(list1);
Set<Foo> fooSet2 = new HashSet<>(list2);

fooSet1.removeAll(list2);
fooSet2.removeAll(list1);

List<Foo> notInIntersectList = Stream.concat(fooSet1.stream(), fooSet2.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Assuming I'd have a non-numeric value as attribute I'm comparing (e.g. a string) would I still need to override the hashCode()? So I see it makes sense to simply override the `equals()`-method, but why do I also need to override the `hashCode`?

Comment: See this - [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: If you put this object in a  hashmap, then you can find it with the correct hashCode function. If you do not override it, it will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot create an `equals` and `hashCode` on your class (maybe they have them already but not based on `boo`), what I would do is:

- Create a `Set<Integer>` (or a `BitSet`) containing all the `boo` values in list 1. Call it `set1`
- Create a `Set<Integer>` (or a `BitSet`) containing all the `boo` values in list 2. Call it `set2`
- Use `set1.retainAll(set2)` to get the intersection of the two sets.
- Use the following to create my list:

  ```
  Stream.concat(list1.stream(),list2.stream())
        .filter(item-> ! set1.contains(item.getBoo()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList);
  ```

This is O(m+n) and also ensures the order of the items in the original lists is maintained, as well as any duplicates (items having the same `boo`).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shall add the methods `equals` and `hashCode` to your class `Foo` (see [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java))

```
class Foo {
    private int boo;
    private int placeholder = 1;

    public Foo(int boo) {
        this.boo = boo;
    }

    public int getBoo() {
        return boo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + boo;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Foo))
            return false;
        Foo other = (Foo) obj;
        return boo == other.boo;
    }

}
```

Now you can use the `removeAll` method of `List`:

> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in
>   the specified collection (optional operation). After this call
>   returns, this collection will contain no elements in common with the
>   specified collection.

You will have to build a new List `notInIntersectList` like that:

```
    List<Foo> listIntersection = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    listIntersection.removeAll(list2);

    List<Foo> notInIntersectList = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    notInIntersectList.addAll(list2);
    notInIntersectList.removeAll(listIntersection);
```

Comment: It seems you are keeping the intersection rather than the items *not* in the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

### avoid Lambda expressions

They make code harder to read, and less efficient.

If you simply use traditional `for` loops, your code should work... plus, you can use `break` to stop searching for a second match.

```
    List<Foo> notInIntersectList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    for(Foo li1foo : list1) {
        boolean inBothLists = false;
        for(Foo li2foo : list2) {
            if (li1foo.getBoo() == li2foo.getBoo()) {
                inBothLists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!inBothLists) {
            notInIntersectList.add(li1foo);
        }
    }
```

You probably still recognize your code there... Now here's the pro version with imperative coding:

```
    List<Foo> notInIntersectList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    nextfoo: for(Foo li1foo : list1) {
        for(Foo li2foo : list2)
            if (li1foo.getBoo() == li2foo.getBoo())
                continue nextfoo;
        notInIntersectList.add(li1foo);
    }
```

This actually has a very clear and explicit logic (and it will make functional fans puke because of the effective "goto"). It's still slow if list2 is huge though, I didn't want to change your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a library for that:

```
Set<String> wordsWithPrimeLength = ImmutableSet.of("one", "two", "three", "six", "seven", "eight");
Set<String> primes = ImmutableSet.of("two", "three", "five", "seven");

SetView<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(primes, wordsWithPrimeLength); // contains "two", "three", "seven"
// I can use intersection as a Set directly, but copying it can be more efficient if I use it a lot.
return intersection.immutableCopy();
```

If you use `difference(Set<E> set1, Set<?> set2)` instead of `intersection(Set<E> set1, Set<?> set2)`, you will get the difference of the two.

With `ImmutableSet.copyOf(Collection<? extends E> elements)` you can create a Set.

It is called Guava and provides many collection operations:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained

The API: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html

Comment: Op wants to have the _non-intersected_ values!

Answer (score 0):

I see here four possible solutions:

1) Avoid lambda expression following @Anony-Mousse's response

2) Include the variable at the class level (not recommended because this boolean is meant for local use):

```
public class Testing {
 boolean inBothLists = true;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Foo> notInIntersectList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
  list1.forEach(li1foo -> {
    inBothLists = false;
    list2.forEach(li2foo -> {
        if (li1foo.getBoo() == li2foo.getBoo()) {
            inBothLists = true;
        }
    });
    if (!inBothLists) {
        notInIntersectList.add(li1foo);
    }
  });

  System.out.println("Intersected values:");
  notInIntersectList.forEach(liInFoo -> {
        System.out.println(liInFoo);
  });

 }
```

3) Using contains method from List (avoiding boolean):

```
List<Foo> notInIntersectList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
list1.forEach(li1foo -> {
    if (!list2.contains(li1foo)) 
        notInIntersectList.add(li1foo);
});
```

4) Java8 Stream API (already mentioned in another answer and avoiding boolean):

```
List<Foo> notInIntersectList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
list1.forEach(li1foo -> {
        Foo result = list2.stream()
                  .filter(li2foo -> li1foo.getBoo() == li2foo.getBoo() )
                  .findAny()
                  .orElse(null);
        if (result == null)
            notInIntersectList.add(li1foo);
});
```

I would go for option 1), 3) or 4). I only kept 2.) to show an example using variables inside lambda functions.

UPDATE: I found 3) and 4) options in a [recent Baeldung post on how to find an Element in a List](https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java)