# CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->... with a non-final variable

Tags: java, lambda, completable-future

I have this code that works fine:

```
String name = "Oscar";
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doX(name));
```

Now I need to add some logic to the `name` variable:

```
String name = "Oscar";
if (x){
  name = "Tiger";
}
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doX(name));
```

But now the compiler complains about `Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final`

I understand from posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final) that the `name` must be `final` or effectively final, but I wonder if there is a way to write the code differently in order to enable the logic on the `name` variable

Comment: If the code is indeed exactly as you wrote it, you could write `String name = x ? "Tiger" : "Oscar";` - this will make for a single initializer. But if the logic is more complicated, this may not work.

Comment: Or possibly copy it into another variable to make it final as well.

Comment: or worst,should not used, Use `String[] name`, and in lambda user `name[0]`.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(name) .thenApplyAsync(this::doX)` use `ClassName::doX` if `doX` is `static`, use `thenAcceptAsync` if `doX` is `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Conditional Operator`, something like this:

```
        boolean condition = true;
        String name = condition ? "Tiger" : "Oscar";
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println(name));
```

Or using if statements:

```
 boolean condition = true;
    final String name;
    if(condition) {
        name = "Tiger";
    }else {
        name = "Oscar";
    }
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println(name));
```

Comment: You can not change the value of a final variable. name = "Tiger" will not work.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi since he did not assign any value to it, it will work. you can assign a value to a final variable only once, which is what he did (if, else)

Answer (score 0):

The lambda expression needs a final variable. If the initialization code is complicated enough then define a new final variable.

```
final String fName = name;
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doX(fName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to decouple resolver logic from the main flow:

```
public static void somewhere() {
    // Variable even may be explicitly final
    final String name = resolve(true);
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doX(name));
}

public String resolve(boolean condition) {
    if (condition)
        return "NameX";

    return "NameY";

    // Or:
    // return condition ? "NameX" : "NameY";
}
```

The advantage of the approach that you may add more complex conditions and can change this logic later without touching the original flow.