# String cannot be converted to list <string> and store that data into database

Tags: java

I want to insert list of string into Database so usual we will store string directly to database by either using prepared statement or batch statement like that but now I want to insert list of string into database so I have used prepared statement

```
List<String> Account_Number = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt"))
    .filter(s -> s.contains(arra.get(7)))
    .map(s -> s.split(":")[1].trim())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(Account_Number);

try {
    Connection conn = PDFTOEXCEL.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into client_info values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    stmt.setString(1, Account_Number.get(1));
    int k = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I have about 31 columns in my database just for showing I have posted only one in this code all are in the list of string only

So now I am getting error in :

```
while (query_set.next()) {
    row_counter = row_counter + 1;
    **Account_Number = query_set.getString("Account_Number");**
```

Output:

> Error:incompatible types: String cannot be converted to List

The bold one is the error statement

Comment: just curious, are you in the same class as the poster of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741312/how-to-use-lamba-expression-without-using-final) or are you the same person?

Comment: no we are two different person working in same project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: What is your question? You've only told us what you want to do, but I see no question. Please read the [ask] guide and [edit] the question to provide enough information (and code) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Account_Number` is of type `List`, and you try to assign a `String` to it. That is not possible: a `String` is not a `List`. Assuming you want to **add** this string to the list, you need to use `Account_Number.add(...)`:

```
Account_Number.add(query_set.getString("Account_Number"));
```

Given you haven't provided a lot of context, it is hard to say if this is actually the right thing to do.

On a separate note, please try to follow common Java naming conventions. Variables and fields should start with a lowercase letter, and usually underscores are avoided, except in constants. So it should be `accountNumber`, not `Account_Number`. Following the conventions will make it easier for people to read your code.