# atomic variables with lambda

Tags: java, atomic

**It is not a duplicate, all duplicate links are suggesting for final but I clearly said I knew about it, what I need is an explanation for the Atomic part.** So the question is why Atomic?

---

Any explanation on why IntelliJ is suggesting to convert it into Atomic.

There was another suggestion to declare final, which I understand the lambda needs to capture the value and doesn't want it to change outside its scope.

```
boolean myvar = true;
env.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    if(value == null) myvar = false;
});
```

after changing to atomic, it looks like this.

```
  AtomicBoolean myvar = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  env.forEach((key, value) -> {
      System.out.println(key + " " + value);
      if(value == null) myvar.set(false);
  });
```

[image]

[image]

after converting to final, it suggests again to convert into one element array.

Comment: You are trying to modify a variable inside lambda expression and this variable was declared outside the body of lambda and is not effectively final. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final).

Comment: can someone please add explanation for Atomic suggestion, I knew final part already. The question is not a duplicate, please read again.

Comment: Because you change it to a reference to an object `AtomicBoolean myvar = new AtomicBoolean(false);` So you will not modify the reference but the value inside the atomic reference object. And modifying the value of reference under AtomicReference is thread safe.

Comment: ok, but I could do it with `Boolean myvar = new Boolean(false)` too, why atomic?

Comment: `Boolean` is also atomic ... in a fatuous sense.   But you would get an error in that case because `myvar` has to be non-final for the assignment to work.  `Boolean` is *immutable*.  It has no setters.

Comment: ok, progressing, I understand atomic operations are thread safe, they perform instruction in a single operation something, that's where I want the discussion to go to, why Atomic here with lambda?

Comment: Using `AtomicXXX` is a suggestion of a correct way to code this.  Not a requirement.   For what it is worth, the issue here is NOT thread-safety.  It is that the Java language *requires* the *variable* to be effectively final ... if it is a local variable.

Comment: ok, why is it a correct way, how does it help the lambda code?

Comment: It helps because using an AtomicXXX is one way to get a mutable object that you can store a value in ... without violating the effectively-final constraint that the Java language places on you.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks. You may please remove the duplicate flag, and post this as an answer for acceptance.

Comment: Nope.   I agree that it is a duplicate.   I am just helping you understand.

Comment: I see, so it was a workaround, otherwise, the atomic operations and thread-safety has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Correct. As the other suggestion says, you could also use a single-element `boolean[]`.