# Alternative to lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Is there an alternative to lambda expressions? With my current code, I can't access the variable maxCnt, modify it, and send it back out to use.

```
int maxCnt = 0;

incoming.stream().forEach(a -> {
    Integer cnt = wordFrequency.get(a);
    if (cnt != null) {
        if (cnt > maxCnt) {
            maxCnt = cnt;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: That's because you're using forEach() instead of map(), filter() and max().https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: Do take a look at [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: Streams should be free from side effects. So when you think you have a need to modify a variable outside the stream, it’s a sign of a bad design (and there are tricks to do it if you insist; however the answers already show a couple of good designs, so in this case you shouldn’t).

Comment: As an aside, assuming that `incoming` is a collection you don’t need a stream. You might have done just `incoming.forEach`.

Answer (score 5):

Sure thing, you can do:

```
int maxCnt = incoming.stream()
          .map(wordFrequency::get)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
          .max().orElse(0);
```

Comment: `wordFrequency::get`?

Comment: How about `int maxCnt = incoming.stream()
                .mapToInt(in -> wordFrequency.getOrDefault(in, 0))
                .summaryStatistics().getMax();` for an alternative?

Comment: @Naman it will be wrong if all the values are negative, and it will compute more statistics for nothing.

Comment: @JBNizet for all negative values, even the current logic in the question and the answer would be wrong. [...and now that I realize, it would actually be inconsistent when the `incoming` is actually empty!!] Compute was something I was also thinking about(when I posted it as a question in comments) and I do second the thought that Optional with orElse could be a preferred choice there.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing requires a lambda. In your case, a for-loop can do the same thing:

```
int maxCnt = 0;
for (var a : incoming) {
    Integer cnt = wordFrequency.get(a);
    if (cnt != null && cnt > maxCnt) maxCnt = cnt;
}
```

This is readable and performs well; you aren't losing anything by not using a lambda—today.

In the future, with advances in the performance of parallel streams *maybe* it will become worthwhile to run even small workloads in parallel. In other words, more streams could default to being parallel instead of sequential. In such a future, using a `Stream` and lambdas instead of this for-loop would allow your code to take advantage of those improvements without a rewrite.