# Incrementing counter in LinkedHashMap using foreach-loop

Tags: java, android, foreach, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I am looping through a LinkedHashMap and incrementing `i` counter and below is how I used to do it using a for-loop.

```java
int i = 0;

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : linkedHashMap.entrySet()) {
      Car car = new Car();

      car.setCarId(String.valueOf(i++));
      car.setCarName(entry.getKey());
      car.setOdometerReading(entry.getValue());

      appRoomRepository.insertCarDetails(car);
}
```

Below is how I want to use a foreach-loop

```
int i = 0;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     linkedHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
           Car car = new Car();

           car.setCarId(String.valueOf(i++));
           car.setCarName(key);
           car.setOdometerReading(value);

           appRoomRepository.insertCarDetails(car);
        });
}
```

I am stuck in this line `car.setCarId(String.valueOf(i++))`;

I keep getting this error "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final". How can I increment counter `i`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expressions can use variables defined in an outer scope
They can capture static variables, instance variables, and local variables, **but only local variables must be final or effectively final**

**Use AtomicInteger:**

````
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

     linkedHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> {

           Car car = new Car();

           car.setCarId(String.valueOf(i.getAndIncrement()));
           car.setCarName(entry.getKey());
           car.setOdometerReading(entry.getValue());

           appRoomRepository.insertCarDetails(car);

        });
}

```
````

Comment: I am getting this error Required type: AtomicInteger Provided: int

Comment: use AtomicInteger method which one you need, incrementAndGet(), getAndIncrement(), decrementAndGet(),  getAndDecrement() etc..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options:

You could iterate with a range

`IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(n ->...`

Or you could use an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and name that 'final'

[Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final) this post has a good discussion of why this needs to happen.

Comment: my range is not limited to 10 its upto n value

Comment: Yeah so then do ```...range(0, n).forEach(i ->...```

The code I linked wasn't specifically for copy/paste, just showing you the syntax