# Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda

When I try to increment "e" in lambda expression, it gives me an "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final" error.
Here is the code:

```java
int e = 0;
new Thread(() -> {
    e++;
});
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: How I can fix it tho? I saw someones code that has 1:1 this code and it doesnt error.

Comment: "*I saw someones code that has 1:1 this code and it doesnt error*" that is very unlikely. Please double-check it and provide link to that resource. You could see *similar* code where lamba/local/anonymous class can use local variable to change some *property* of object (like `person.setName("Adam");`) held by variable, but it can't *reassign* new value to local variable.

Comment: Also see: https://www.baeldung.com/java-effectively-final

Comment: There are few ways around it, but picking proper solution would require more information about what you are trying to do. For instance instead of `int` you could use `AtomicInteger` which provides *methods* to modify/read its *state* (integer value).