# How to convert following Java code to Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to convert the following Java code to Java 8. I have written the following code to calculate the average temperatures.

```
public static double calculateTemps(String country, Map<String, List<Temperatures>> tempMap) {
    double temp = 0.0f;
    int count = 0;

    if (country.equalsIgnoreCase("India")) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Temperatures>> m : tempMap.entrySet()) {
            for (Temperatures t : m.getValue()) {
                temp = temp + t.getTemp();
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    return temp / count;
}
```

The above code is working fine. Now, I am trying to convert it to Java 8. I have written the following code, but I am getting compile-time errors

```
public static double calculateTemps(String country, Map<String, List<Temperatures>> tempMap) {
    double temp = 0.0f;
    int count = 0;

    tempMap.entrySet().stream().filter(temps -> temps.getKey()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("India"))
            .forEach(temps -> {
                temp = temp + temps.getValue();
            }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

I thought map is better suited here, but after going through a few questions on Stack Overflow I thought for-each is better suited here. Not sure. Could anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: You should use reduce instead of forEach, to sum your filtered entries. And there's no reason to collect since you don't need that collection for something.

Comment: Note that the code is already Java 8.  What you actually means is ... how should you convert it to use Java 8+ streams.  Also, note that converting "looping" code to use streams won't necessarily improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

1. You're trying to add `Temperatures` objects to `temp` instead of `Temperatures.getTemp()`
2. You're trying to modify variable `temp` inside a lambda, but `temp` must be effectively final
3. You're calling `collect` on the void method `forEach`, which is not possible.

You can make use of features of `DoubleStream` to calculate the average:

```java
return tempMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(temps -> temps.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("India"))
        .flatMap(temps -> temps.getValue().stream())
        .mapToDouble(temp -> temp.getTemp())
        .average().orElse(0.0);
```

As an aside, the `filter` condition is different from the condition used in the original method (which checked against the `country` parameter), but I have preserved it from your original attempt. Check carefully if it is really what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the code
Point#1. Corrected and understood
#2. Do you have any online source pointing to variable declarations inside lambda expressions
#3. My bad. for-Each and collect are terminal ops. By mistake I had added both at last minute

Comment: @nikhiludgirkar For example, [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: Actually,  the original Code uses `country.equalsIgnoreCase("India")`, where you use `temps.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("India"))`.

Comment: @DorianGray I explicitly point that out below the code. I did that as it was what the OP did in their original attempt to translate this to streams.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
public static double calculateTemps(String country, Map<String, List<Temperatures>> tempMap) {
    return tempMap.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .filter(temps -> temps.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("India"))
                  .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
                  .mapToDouble(Temperatures::getTemp)
                  .average()
                  .orElse(0.0);
}
```

Comment: `flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue())` should be `flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())`

Answer (score 1):

you can reference like this:

```
    public static double calculateTemps(String country, Map<String, List<Temperatures>> tempMap) {
        double temp = 0.0f;
        int count = 0;

        if (country.equalsIgnoreCase("India")) {

            double result = tempMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
                    .mapToDouble(Temperatures::getTemp)
                    .average().orElse(0.0);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is no good reason for that intermediate `collect`, you can directly use the stream returned by the `flatMap` operation.

Comment: you are right .