# Read arrays from Firestore and put them inside an ArrayList - Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an application that can read the values from a Firestore array and put them into an ArrayList or something, this is my code:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> driverPermissions = new ArrayList<>();

    Firestore.collection("Admins").document("1234567890").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        driverPermissions = document.get("Test");
    });
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It marks me as an error in this line:

```
driverPermissions = document.get("Test");
```

And the error is:

> Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

How can I add the values present inside the array on Firestore into an ArrayList or something like that and then use that throughout the code? And not only within the method?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 driverPermissions = document.getString("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to get data type String but You declared Array tn Integer first mistake.

Then try this

```
Firestore.collection("Admins").document("1234567890").get().
addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
   ArrayList<String> driverPermissions = (ArrayList<String>) 
   document.get("Test");
});
```

Here you can store only store string type data.

Or you can try like this

```
ArrayList<Object> driverPermissions = New ArrayList<>();

Firestore.collection("Admins").document("1234567890").get().
addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
   driverPermissions.add(new String(document.get("Test")); // When Storing STring
driverPermissions.add(new Integer(document.get("Test")); // When Storing Integer

});
```

Here you can store any kind of data can be integer can be string But You have to declared what kind of data your storing.

On Demand Way

```
ArrayList<String> driverPermissions = New ArrayList<String>();

Firestore.collection("Admins").document("1234567890").get().
addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
   DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
   driverPermissions.add(document.get("Test")); Or
   driverPermissions.add(""+document.get("Test"));
});
```

Another way

```
 ArrayList<String> driverPermissions;
Firestore.collection("Admins").document("1234567890").get().
addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
   driverPermissions = (ArrayList<String>) 
   document.get("Test");
});
```

Comment: Hi Kayes, the first code only works if I want to use the list inside the method, in fact it doesn't recognize it outside. The second code is what I am trying to do since the list, being declared outside the method, can be safely used throughout the code. For how you wrote the second code it gives an error:
Cannot resolve constructor 'String (java.lang.Object)'
What can I do?

Comment: second code you can keep any kind of data just you have cast type of data which you gonna trying to store.

Comment: The array in the database consists of strings only. In your second code I have kept only the part that works with them and not with integers. But it doesn't work, the error is what I wrote before.

Comment: Then Replace Object As String on second code , and inside remove type cast new String Part and Paranthesis as well , Hope it will work.

Comment: I did as you said, but nothing.
It gives me an error: Cast parameter to java.lang.string and suggests me to change the line of code like this: driverPermissions.add ((String) document.get ("Test")). But once I run the code it crashes and generates this error: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: ArrayList<String> driverPermissions = New ArrayList<String>();

driverPermissions.add(document.get ("Test"));

Comment: I did this, it doesn't work

Comment: I added new way and Change The code check please

Comment: In thise line: driverPermissions = (ArrayList<String>) gives me an error: Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247080/discussion-between-andrea-and-kayes-fahim).

Answer (score 0):

A variable that is used in a lambda expression should always be final or [effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final), and you cannot change that. To solve this, you either make the variable a member of the class or define it and initialize it inside the `onComplete()`.

> How can I add the values present inside the array on Firestore into an ArrayList or something like that and then use that throughout the code? And not only within the method?

[There is no way you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679). Firebase API is asynchronous, meaning that any code that needs data from Cloud Firestore, needs to be inside the `onComplete()` method, or be called from there. You cannot simply use it outside the callback, even if the field is a member of the class. So to solve this you can use a custom callback as seen in that answer. The reason is that you need to wait for the data. If you understand Kotlin, you might also be interested in reading the following resource:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)

In Java, you should consider using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata). I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM) might also help.

P.S. If you need at some point in time to use an array of objects, here is another helpful resoruce:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: Hey Andrea. Can I help you with other information?