# Filter a list of JSON objects based on values of one or more key that are known only at run time

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, predicate

```
List<JSONObject> myObj = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
myObj.add(new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"name1\",\"sub-name\":\"sub-name1\", \"designation\":\"d1\", \"mgr\": \"m1\"}"));
myObj.add(new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"name1\",\"sub-name\":\"sub-name2\", \"designation\":\"d2\", \"mgr\": \"m2\"}"));
myObj.add(new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"name2\",\"sub-name\":\"sub-name3\", \"designation\":\"d2\", \"mgr\": \"m1\"}"));
myObj.add(new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"name2\",\"sub-name\":\"sub-name4\", \"designation\":\"d3\", \"mgr\": \"m2\"}"));
myObj.add(new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"name3\",\"sub-name\":\"sub-name5\", \"designation\":\"d3\", \"mgr\": \"m3\"}"));
```

From this list the requirement is to be able to filter objects based on values passed for various keys.

For e.g. return objects

1. where name=name1 and mgr=m1
2. where designation=d2
3. where mgr=m2
4. where name=name1 or mgr=m1

Filtering the stream can work based on such conditions

```
List<JSONObject> filterObj = myObj.stream().filter(e -> e.get("name").equals("name1") && e.get("mgr").equals("m1")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I tried to see if a custom predicate can be built without much success.

How can this filtering be dynamically when the keys and values are not know upfront?

Comment: What have you tried and why didn’t it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? Is it [this one](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)? How do you obtain the relevant keys (and values) at runtime? Are they entered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for a AND condition

```java
List<String> filterConditions = new ArrayList<>();
filterConditions.add("designation:d1");
filterConditions.add("mgr:m1");

List<JSONObject> filterObj = myObj.stream().filter(e -> {
    Boolean flag = false;

    for (String i : filterConditions) {
        if (e.get(StringUtils.substringBefore(i, ":")).equals(StringUtils.substringAfter(i, ":"))) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag ? true : false;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. Did this with a for loop in the filter condition. It gives the desired result. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).