# Populating an existing Set<String> via Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java streams and functional programming and I wonder if my question will ever even have a valid use case or it is just not meaningful.
I have the following code that gives me a Set from an array

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String []arr = {"a","abc","b","cd"};
        Set<String> dict = new HashSet<>();
        Arrays.stream(arr).map(item->{
            System.out.println(item);
            dict.add(item);
            return dict;
        });

//        dict = Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        System.out.println(dict);
    }
```

This gives me an empty dict. If I do it the way I have in second last line, it works. Is there a way to mutate already instantiated `dict` that was instantiated outside stream that it gets populated in the `map` function?

Comment: Here is an Oracle article on _[Processing Data with  Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)_.

Comment: As a note, in Java, the term _dictionary_ typically refers to a list of key-value pairs, and not a set.  Additionally, the method `map`, here, is not related to a `Map` collection; it is used to _"... project the elements of a stream into another form."_.

Answer (score 5):

`Stream.map()` is an *intermediate operation*, meaning it only stages a step of the pipeline, but it doesn't do anything when you call it. You need a *terminal operation* to put the stream to work. In your case, you can use `forEachOrdered()`:

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .forEachOrdered(dict::add);
```

Note: I'm assuming there's a reason you need to modify an existing set rather than produce a new one. Otherwise, just use `collect()` as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: This code violates the "no side-effects rule".

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis `forEachOrdered()` exists to support side-effects

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know it serves exactly such a purpose. Do you have a reference to any documentation supporting this statement?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis, the violation is a minimum, _"... Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed."_, from _[Stream (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)._

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis It's logical; if it doesn't return anything, it must be acting on something. But you can find mention of it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) with respect to `forEach()`. `forEachOrdered()` is only different in that it guarantees order and visibility, which solves half the issue of side-effects.

Comment: The main place you want to avoid side-effects is in intermediate operations. Using `forEach()` and `forEachOrdered()` is more of a judgement call. Normally I'd prefer something like `toSet()` of course, but in a case where you already have an existing set that you want to update with a stream, terminal side-effects are perfectly appropriate.

Comment: you can use  `toSet()` to create a new set an *feed* it into the existing Set using `addAll` to be *more functional* - but that will create an additional instance of `Set` and would not increase readability (IMO)

Comment: @user16320675 Agreed. I would sooner replace the stream with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

1. Before the question got edited, the commented part didn't compile because `dict` must be either final or effectively final. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final) for more information.
2. One of the few rules of using Stream API is to avoid side effects. The JavaDoc for [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) package describes it well with examples:

   > Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.
3. The gist of each Stream is to return **a new collection/value** through operations such as filtering, mapping, reducing, or advanced collecting. It was never meant to modify an existing one. The correct way how to transform the array `arr` into a set is:

   ```java
   Set<String> dict = Arrays.stream(arr)
         .peek(item -> System.out.println(item)) // optional for debugging
         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
   ```

Comment: why use peek here? Because in my original code, I have a println?

Comment: 1. does not compile? was the question edited (in the first 5 minutes)? Posted code is valid java code and should compile. || 2. "in general discouraged" is not exactly a "rule" || 3. "return **a new collection/value** is just one use case

Comment: @user16320675 1) The question was edited. 2) It does not justify its usage either. 3) Name more?

Comment: @curiousengineer Yes, exactly. Feel free to move it away.

Comment: @user16320675 1) I have edited my answer. Remember I can't check each minute what the OP changed in the code to keep my wording 100% correct. The gist is clear: One cannot use non-(effectively) final variable in a lambda expression. It does not matter whether the `dict` assignment happens before or after the lambda expression definition as in both cases it strips the effectively-final characteristics from `dict`. 2) + 3) You still didn't provide a legit use-case when the procedural approach in Stream API shall be used instead of the declarative way.

Comment: 1) exactly the reason ("can't check each minute") why I added the comment to start with... 2+3) Why should I?It is not about justifying its usage, nor about being legit (very opinion-based - for me posted question can be a legit use-case - it may not be in a pure functional language, but Java isn't such)

Comment: Furthermore, the term _closure_, and the concept of a functional-paradigm is to reduce mutating; or in this case re-assignment.

Comment: Note that `peek()` also operates via side-effect by definition. But that's fine here; there's no hard rule against side-effects, as @user16320675 explained.