# Why do variables passed to runnable need to be final? How to fix the problem?

Tags: java, for-loop

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class NewTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mystr = "banana";

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < mystr.length(); i++) {
            Runnable task = () -> {
                System.out.print(mystr.charAt(i));
            };

            executor.submit(task);
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the fix already in the question's title?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Comment: I got the error: : local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final, but don't know how to solve the problem caused by the variable i

Comment: @Lesleyys, this is because of _[lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope)_.  The _task_ object here is being assigned an _anonymous class_, a different scope entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They need to be final because of the fakery that the variables inside your `Runnable` are the same variables as outside: actually, they are different variables, with the same names.

In order for that not to be confusing, Java forces the value of variables used inside the `Runnable` to be final (or effectively final) in order that they cannot be changed inside or outside the `Runnable`, meaning they must have the same value inside and outside.

The fix is simple: assign `i` to another (final) variable inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mystr.length(); i++) {
    int ii = i;  // ii is effectively final.
    Runnable task = () -> {
        System.out.print(mystr.charAt(ii));
    };
    // ...
}
```