# How to use final variable within forEach method

Tags: java

```java
final List<String> categoryCodeProductTypes = new ArrayList<>();
List<Uda> uda4 = udas.stream()
                     .filter(a -> a.getCode().equals(Uda_Code))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
uda4.stream()
    .forEach(a -> {
                   final String categoryCodeProductType = "";
                   categoryCodeProductTypes.add(categoryCodeProductType);
                   a.getReferences()
                    .stream()
                    .forEach(b -> {
                                   categoryCodeProductType = categoryCodeProductType.concat(b.getCode());
                                  });
                  });
return categoryCodeProductTypes;
```

I get error in `categoryCodeProductType = categoryCodeProductType.concat(b.getCode());` saying remove final keyword but I can't. Is there any other way we can fix this?

Comment: Why can't you remove the `final` keyword?

Comment: Use a different variable? Don't use a string, rather a string buffer (or whatever the current string buffer-y hotness is in Java these days)?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the nature of this question: if it's your code, why can't you remove it? If it's not, is it some sort of pop quiz? (Hint: they say it's always the red wire but it isn't.)

Comment: Ada and Dave, variables used inside a closure in Java must be effectively `final`. I'm guessing OP tried without the `final` keyword, saw an error that said "This variable must be `final`", and rolled with it without understanding what the `final` keyword does.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but read [Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final). The concept is explained, some answers have workarounds as well.

Comment: @Ada if i remove final i will get error categoryCodeProductTypes.add(categoryCodeProductType); asking for initialize the variable.

Comment: also i will get error in  categoryCodeProductType.concat(b.getCode()); this line saying the variable must be final

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign a `final` variable. And you can only use effectively-`final` variables (that is, `final` variables or those that could've been declared as such) inside of closures. So if you want to mutate a string inside of a closure, you'll need to use a mutable string type like [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
final StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
someStream.forEach(value -> {
    myStringBuilder.append(value.getCode());
});
final String result = myStringBuilder.toString();
```

We never actually *reassign* the variable `myStringBuilder`, so it can still be `final`. But we can *mutate* it in-place. This is also more efficient than continually allocating new strings for concatenation, as `StringBuilder` will use a mutable buffer internally and save on copying.

Comment: if i am using StringBuilder i cant use add() .that is the problem here

Comment: @MohammedMuntazim `myStringBuilder().toString()` can be invoked at any time to get the current String value in that builder.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Uda` has method `getReferences` which returns something that can be streamed, for example some kind of collection.

You want to concatenate the code of each element (in the collection returned by method `getReferences`) into a single string and then you want to collect all those strings into a `List`.

If the above summary is correct, then consider the below [uncompiled and untested] code:

```java
uda4.stream()
    .map(a -> a.getReferences()
               .stream()
               .map(b -> b.getCode())
               .collect(Collectors.joining()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically, the `map` method returns a stream of strings where each string is the concatenation of all the codes in the collection returned by method `getReferences`. All that remains is to collect all the strings, that the `map` method produces, to a `List`.

Note that I cannot compile nor test the above code as you did not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You adding `categoryCodeProductTypes.add(categoryCodeProductType);`
And two lines below you are loosing ability to modify this object by reassigning attempt.
Dont use .forEach instead of iterator with no reason. You will see for yourself why this code is inappropriate by results it will produce.
That's closest to your approach:

```
    class Main {
    
    @Getter
    static class A {
        List<B> references;
    }

    @Getter
    static class B {
        String code;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<StringBuilder> categoryCodeProductTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        var uda4 = List.of(new A());
        uda4.forEach(a -> {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            categoryCodeProductTypes.add(builder);
            a.getReferences().forEach(b -> builder.append(b.getCode()));
        });
        List<String> result = categoryCodeProductTypes.stream().map(StringBuilder::toString).toList();
    }
}
```

It's not the best way of mapping the data. Converting into intermediate controlled objects piece by piece is much better than trying to do it on the fly at one time.